# ASP.NET Core Web app with Identity - Where do I add EntityFramework code?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Bit of a noob question I'm afraid.  I have an ASP.NET Core Web Application, which uses Individual User Account for authentication so it's brought in the Identity bits and created me migrations and an "ApplicationDbContext" for all of the user/roles stuff.  I moved the Data related classes, migrations etc into a separate class project to separate it from the MVC project, but other than that it's out-of-the-box.  All good.  My DB has been created by migrations and I can register and login.

Now, I'm coming to build my app, and I'm not sure where is best to add my entities. The question is should I

1) Add my entities to the "ApplicationDbContext" which was created for me by Visual Studio?

2) Create a second DbContext instance in my Data project?

3) Something else?

I understand that if my app was to use separate databases for authentication and domain data then it would be a no brainer and option 2 would be the answer.  But this app is very simple with one database, so I'm wondering if I may be able to get away with option 1.

The ApplicationDbContext that was created for me inherits from IdentityDbContext.  I don't know if that has other implications if I were to go with option 1 and add my entities to ApplicationDbContext.

I did start down the road of option 2, but quickly found that things like Add-Migration wouldn't work when the project had 2 contexts.  I found that the Add-Migration command now has a -context switch which can be used to tell the command which context to use, but I'm a bit concerned that I will run into other issues.  Particularly I am going to be using VS Team Services to build and deploy the app to Azure using continuous deployment, and I don't know if those build and release features will cope with the multiple DB contexts.

Any advice from somebody in the know?  This has got to be a pretty standard requirement, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence your app is very simple one,you can use `ApplicationDbContext` for your domain models as well.That means, I would like to recommend you to use single context class for your app.If you do so,you can easily manage your business requirements (i.e. any relations between your classes) with the `users` and `Roles` on the `IdentityDbContext` context.